# ros-electric-desktop-full not found

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, linux, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to install ROS Electric on an [iMX53 Quick Start board](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=IMX53QSB) running Lucid Linux 10.04. It is an ARM Cortex A8. I am following the directions for Lucid at http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu. Everything goes well until:

"sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full"

returns: "E: Couldn't find package ros-electric-desktop-full"

Suggestions? My skill level is high and I have previously successfully installed Electric on Maverick on an x86.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12889/ros-electric-desktop-full-not-found/) by [StrongEnough](https://answers.ros.org/users/1519/strongenough/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-04**:
I'm not sure you can get Cortex A8 precompiled .debs. AFAIK, only i386 and amd64 are packaged right now. See also http://www.ros.org/debbuild/electric.html

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-04**:
I meant apt-get update, not upgrade.

**Comment by [StrongEnough](https://answers.ros.org/users/1519/strongenough/) on 2012-02-04**:
I searched for this problem and saw nothing. Now, on the right, I see this issue http://answers.ros.org/question/1776/error-while-successful-sudo-apt-get-install-ros. Is it possible this is a mirror issue too? I'll look around for a way to change the mirror. I'm not a Linux expert yet.

**Comment by [StrongEnough](https://answers.ros.org/users/1519/strongenough/) on 2012-02-04**:
Yes, You say "sudo apt-get upgrade" but I did "sudo apt-get update" per the instructions. Is that the problem? I don't have enough Karma to upload a screen shot, but in the Lucid "Software Sources, Other Software" tab; the item "http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main" is checked.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-04**:
Did you update the sources list? Is it correct? Did you apt-get upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to build from source, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

---

Originally posted by [Kent Williams](https://answers.ros.org/users/1646/kent-williams/) with karma: 91 on 2012-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-04**:
Agreed. There are some debs available for ARM, but not nearly the full set that are available on x86. See http://ros.org/debbuild/electric.html for the current build status.